# Get the text of ContentEditable span element and set it to textbox's text simultaneosly

Tags: jquery

```
<span contentEditable="true" id="00elm" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length<= 80);">CLICK TO CHANGE</span>
<input type="text" id="txt01" />
```

While the user is editing the span element by typing, simultaneously textbox will have the same text. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#00elm').keyup(function(){
    $('#txt01').val($(this).text())
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/36/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want with out jQuery try this code:

```
<span contentEditable="true" id="00elm" onkeyup="document.getElementById('txt01').value = ( this.innerText.length<=80 ? this.innerText : document.getElementById('txt01').value );">CLICK TO CHANGE</span>
```

and demo here http://jsfiddle.net/26hwm75n/1/